# 100% footer with inner div same width of wrapper

Tags: css, footer

I have read many forums and posts now but nothing seems to get exactly what my issue is. I have a footer (using WordPress blank theme) that is 100% width at the bottom of the page, no worries there. I have 3 div's within an "foot" div which is inside the  HTML 5 hook. I want that inner div "foot" to be the same width and stay the same as the wrapper above it, so that it looks to be the same width as the wrapper @ 960px wide. I am struggling to figure out how to make this happen. You can see my code and css, as I am sure you know how with google chrome or firefox firebug, at http://newsite.dramanotebook.com. Let me know what you think is the best solution, even if that means having to change up the page/footer templates to make what I want happen.

I wish to have the `<footer>` to be 100% width to expand the width of the users window and the `<div id="foot">` to be restricted to 960px width. Here is the catch. I want to have that `<div id="foot">` to stay in vertical alignment with the rest of the site above. `<div id="wrapper"></div>` I am referring to.

```
<div id="wrapper" class="hfeed">
<header>

<div id="branding">
</header>
<div id="container">
<div id="main" class="clearfix">
<!-- I have removed all the bloat in the middle to keep to my issue at hand -->
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div> <!-- end of container div -->
</div> <!-- end of wrapper div -->
<footer> <!-- what I was referring to by HTML hook, my apologies "element"-->
<div id="foot">
    <div id="left-footer">
        <div id="trustwave_img">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://sealserver.trustwave.com/seal.js?code=5d243334f2474482a03b5e1f5d5fe4f5"></script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="center-footer">

    </div>
    <div id="right-footer">

    </div>
</div>
</footer>
```

Below is the related CSS I currently have, which I am sure there are smarter folks out here that can help me improve to get where I need, and learn something along the way :).

```
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Helvetica, Verdana;
  color: #424242;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  background: #fdffd0;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  Position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #cccccc;  

}
#container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
footer {
  clear:both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    background-color: #A4EDA1; /*#9BE398;*/
    opacity: .8;
}
footer #foot {
    width: 960px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: 127px;
    position: relative;
}
#left-footer {
    width: 241px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#center-footer {
    width: 496px;
    margin-left: 365px;
    height: 100%;
}
#right-footer {
    width: 240px;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Do you want all 3 `<div>` in the footer to be 960px wide? I see that you have an image in the first, but the other two are empty.

Comment: If possible, could you please post the relevant code with your question, along with a demo/example of what you have versus what you want? I don't see a `div` by the name of "foot", I don't understand what you mean by "HTML 5 hook", and I don't know what element you're referring to by "wrapper above it". It would really help if you could show us an example instead of asking us to dig through all the HTML and CSS to find the issue on your live site.

Comment: I apologize, I did not provide a code sample as I was trying to allow everyone to see the relevant example page.

Comment: @teddyrised: I want all 3 '<div>' to be within the '<div id="foot">' with an inline layout. I will edit my above posting to include the relevant code and see if I can detail what I want.

Comment: you know that your example-page doesnt include the `id="foot"` element?

Comment: OMG, I am so sorry everyone. I totally forgot I had a custom template for the home page. Thank you for pointing that out. Here is a link that expresses it: http://newsite.dramanotebook.com/about/

Answer (score 1):

center your `#foot` with margin auto.

```
footer #foot {
    width: 960px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: I tried that. No effect. When I increase the width of the browser the `#foot` moves. And I corrected the home page HTML to include the `<div id="foot">`.

Comment: i changed the css to have the `position:relative` included, to let your position-absolutes relate to this element. This solves your question, IMHO. For a better way to solve your problem try teddyrised's approach.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the `margin: 0 auto;` is not working for the `#foot` element is because you are absolutely positioning the inner `<div>`s in that element. When you absolutely position them, you are taking them out of the default flow of the document and the margin and floats will no longer be applicable.

All you need is to remove...

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

...from the `#left-footer` and `#right-footer` selectors.

If you want to create a three column footer in that element, there is no need to specify different floats, margins and etc. for each for the child `<div>`. Instead, just use:

```
footer {
    overflow: hidden; /* Used to clear floats */
    width: 100%;
}
footer > div {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* To define the total width (padding plus border, if any) at the specified width and not more */
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
```

p/s: There are some problems with your CSS - it is not necessary to clear the float in the `<footer>` element (makes no sense), and the `position` property has been mispelled for the `#wrapper`. Your `<div id="header">` is also not properly closed in the HTML code you've posted.

Comment: Thank you Teddy. I am pretty sure I just deleted too much code when I was trying to shorten it up for length of the post. But I will double check. In the 3 `<div>` child elements I need the left and right to be 200px and the center `<div>` to be 460px. I will play with it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `box-sizing` can still be applied when you're using pixels as the unit of measurement :) Here's a more detailed article addressing the use, and functionality of, `box-sizing` http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/.

If you want fixed width, it's even easier - simply make sure that all 3 `<div>` have widths that add up to 960px. You may have borders and padding for each of them, but `box-sizing` will take care of that.